# How to add code in the editor

Tags: support, editor, code

I want to know how to add code tags in this editor. As an example if I want to post an answer in PHP, as soon as I type "open php" my line disappears. How to post PHP with open and close?

Comment: type code, select it and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: Or 4 space indentation for each line and a blank line just above the first line.

Answer (score 5):

You should indent code by 4 spaces. This puts it in

```
code markdown
```

Alternatively, you can put the code between backticks. This also puts things in `code markdown`.

As @Sagar V observes in their [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298066/how-to-add-codes-in-editor/298067#comment967496_298066), you can just select the code block, and click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. This also indents the code by 4 spaces.

The reason your PHP code seems to disappear, is that it opens with "<". Now the editor thinks it's markup, and tries to treat it as such.
By putting your PHP in code markdown, the editor knows that it is code and should be formatted as such.

Please use code markdown only for code!